# Function sjt.dt: function not found

Tags: r, error-handling, sjplot

I've just tried installing the package sjPlot as follows:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("sjPlot/devel")
library(sjPlot)
```

When I try running the following code with the sjt.df() function that is suppose to included into the package:

```
sjt.df(iris,
file="sjt_des.doc") #CRUCIAL - save this as a
#word document
```

It pops out the following error:

```
Error in sjt.df(iris, file = "sjt.des.doc") : 
  could not find function "sjt.df"
```

Do you know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: `sjt.df` [is not exported by `sjPlot`](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/69d24a9782cabb8a530018d6c215a076cfce845a/NAMESPACE); in version 2.5.0, `sjt.df` was replaced by `tab_df`, I think. Check your version, then read through its `NEWS` file, and see what other changes occurred that will impact your code.

Comment: yep it seems excatly as you said. Thanks